# Extract Hangul records from sqlanywhere database using C# library

Tags: c#, encoding, error-handling, sqlanywhere

I am finding the method for extracting `hangul` data from `sqlanywhere` database by using c# library

Now, I'm using `iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere` library. And, I didn't install sqlanywhere DBMS, but I'm using `dbeng10.exe` for launching server.

I want to extract Hangul(Korean) data from database. I try to extract data, but all data of Hangul is abnormally extracted.

I want to find a solution.

Comment: If you can show how you tried to extract data, you have a better chance of getting help.